# Python: default keyword arguments depending on variable length arguments

Tags: python

Is it possible to define a function in Python, such that it accepts a variable length arguments, and a keyword argument, whose default value depends on the variable length arguments?

Something like

```
def f(*args, what = [ True ] * len(*args))
```

The above code gives the error

```
NameError: name 'args' is not defined
```

A use of this would be to pass an arbitrary long list of variables, and, say, an boolean array `what` indicating if some operation has to be done on the passed arguments.
That would need the constraint that the length of `what` has to match that of args.
If omitted, `what` should default to an array of `True`s.

Comment: No. Accept `None` as default argument, and inside the function do `if what is None: what = [True] * len(args)`…

Comment: You may need to wait for this [pep](https://peps.python.org/pep-0671/) to be accepted and implemented.

Comment: @deceze thanks for your comment, that's in fact a solution. If you convert your comment to an answer, I would accept it.